# What is the best way to show a message to user and redirect to home page when a session times out

Tags: asp.net

I am currently working on a asp.net 3.5 web application which is being used by 500 + concurrent users and the session time-out is set to 24 hours but  a recycling of ASPNet process on the server is scheduled to trigger everyday at 3:00 A.M.  is causing the session gets timed out.

What is the best way to show a message to user and redirected to home page  after session is expired? There are lot of pages in the project, so adding code to every page of the site is not really a good solution.

Thanks in advance
BB

Answer (score -1):

You can use global.asax's session end event to perform your redirect & notification. Just a note, that the session doesn't end when the browser is closed. It ends when the session timeout reached.

```
void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E) {
    // Clean up session resources
}
```

Comment: That won't really help on the client.